# Execution priority of threads in waiting queue and entry queue when calling notifyAll

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm struggling a bit to understand the order in which waiting threads get executed once I call notifyAll on a certain object. There is a code example added later, which I will be referencing.

In short, can I be sure that if I have 100 threads named "ABC" in the waiting queue and 100 threads named "GHI" in the entry queue, all "ABC" threads will be executed before "GHI" threads?

When I'm running the short program, it seems that's always the case since "GHI" threads always print out "0", which denotes all "ABC" threads have finished execution by then. I'm just wondering - is this my system/implementation specific or can I be sure this will always be the case? From Java documentation I could not find guarantees about this - but maybe I didn't search in the right place.

Here is the short sample code I was referencing and which always gives consistent results for me:

```
public class Main {
    private volatile int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Main main = new Main();
        // add 100 threads that will all go to wait
        main.addThreads("ABC");

        // wait for 100 threads to be created and then notify all after sleeping 10s
        main.waitForThreads();

        // make sure thread has managed to start and is holding the lock and slpeeping
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        // add a lot more consumers to entry queue
        main.addThreads("GHI");

        //wait for threads to finish
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    }

    private void waitForThreads() throws InterruptedException {
        while (this.count < 99) {
            System.out.println("Not enough waiting threads yet");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main.this.syncMethod();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }, "DEF");
        t.start();
    }

    private void addThreads(String threadName) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Main.this.syncMethod();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }}, threadName).start();;
        }
    }

    private synchronized void syncMethod() throws InterruptedException {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        if (name.equals("ABC")) {
            this.count++;
            this.wait();
            this.count--;
        } else if (name.equals("DEF")) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            this.notifyAll();
            System.out.println("Waiting threads notified");
        } else {
            System.out.println(this.count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on Java scheduler. You create 100 threads which are waiting on the same blockade. If you invoke `notifyAll()`, all these threads wake up, so now you have threads "ABC" and "DEF" working "in the same time". The scheduler grants execution right, so it depands on scheduler. One time you can have that result, another time you will have other.

Comment: I also thought that there would be different results from time to time but so far I haven't managed to get any different output. That's why I was wondering if the consistent results are somehow related to my system specifics.

Comment: I suggest you disable these `sleep()` invokes in `syncMethod()` and in main - only first one. Try to use also `Thread.yield()` into `run()` method inside `addThreads()`. You can also decrease number of threads, let say 10. On my computer in this circumstances result is nondeterministic. It seems that you obtain your order by sleeping the threads. You have also very short thread's tasks inside "ABC" threads, so it propably was finished first, before the end of "DEF" threads.

Comment: Note that relying on this kind of synchronization is very dangerous and it can cause in deadlocks in future. If you would like to wait on some threads for the another threads you should use special Java objects, like `CyclicBarrier`, `CountDownLatch` or simply `join()` method.

Comment: What are the 'waiting queue' and 'entry queue'?